# Difference between straight calling a method and using the '.call' method ? JS

Tags: javascript, callback, prototype

What is the difference in javascript of calling a method this way

```
_callback.call(this, "mystring");
```

instead of

```
_callback("mystring");
```

edit:
if I am not in need of a context, or i'm fine with the one i'm in, i might say it's useless to do it?

Comment: with `call`, you can set the function context (this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call` allows you to specify a different value for `this` inside the function being called.

The first example is called in the context of whatever `this` is in the function it is being called from.

The second example is called in the context of the default object (in a browser that will be `window`, or `undefined` in strict mode).

Answer (score 1):

you can set the context when you call a function with 'call'  i.e inside function 'this' refer to which object.

For further details check this link :

```
http://hangar.runway7.net/javascript/difference-call-apply
```